# Query for seaching for a result obtained from various tables

Tags: mysql

I'm simplifying as much as posible but I have two tables:

one table containing the data called "`bill`"

| ID | discount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 |
| 2 | 0.90 |
| 3 | 0.10 |

And another containing the items, called "`items`"

| ID | IDbill | item | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 1.50 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | b | 6.00 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | c | 3.00 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | a | 1.50 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | d | 5.00 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | c | 3.00 | 1 |

With the total being the sum of (`items.price` * `items.quantity`) matching the `IDbill` with the `ID` from table `bill`, and then multiplied by "`1-bill.discoun`" of that ID

How do I make the query for searching for the result? For example, search "`....WHERE ´total´ = '2.7'`" AND return the ID 3 from bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have over-simplified your scenario but based on what you ask:

```
select i.IDBill
from items i
join bill b on b.id = i.idbill
group by i.IDBill
having sum(price * quantity * (1 - b.discount)) = 1.9;
```

See this [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/840YvAAF)

Returns `2` as expected.

Comment: Thanks!. Definitivelly thats somethig, but that query only calculates for one row on items table. I mean, if you seach for 1.9 (that is the result for ID 2) it doesnt return anything. 
The query returns the result for individual rows on items table, but not the total for the bill ID

Comment: @dvd251996 it's not completely clear from your question or the example you provided, however you need to aggregate and filter using `having`, I have updated the query above, does that now work for you?